# Can I pass a function and a varying number of arguments to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods

can someone say what the best method to do this would be?

I want to have a function, `overall_function` that I pass other functions to. But the other functions don't always have the same or type of arguments.

So what would be the correct syntax to do:

```py
    def overall_function(function, arguments):
        function(arguments)
        do other stuff
```

I'd like arguments to be:

`arg1 = 'foo', arg2 = 53, ...`

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take variable number of arguments:

```
def overall_function(function, *positional, **keyword):
    function(*positional, **keyword)
```

Now, you can pass the arguments like:

```
overall_function(function, 1, 2, foo='bar')
```

and this will execute the function as:

```
function(1, 2, foo='bar')
```

- `positional` would be a `tuple`: `(1, 2)` (these two are positional arguments).
- `keyword` would be a `dict`: `{'foo': 'bar'}` (this is a keyword argument).

Comment: What is the difference between one and two stars?
Is one star if I'm passing the arguments I want in order. And 2 stars if I want to stated what argument it refers to? i.e. arg1='foo'?
thanks!

Comment: @Agustin I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for `*args` and `**kwargs`

```
def overall_function(function, *args, **kwargs):
    function(*args, **kwargs)
    do other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off passing in a lambda as opposed to two arguments so you can delay the execution of the function till you need it, and still keeping the parameters contained together

```
def overall_function(lambda_func):
    lambda_func()


overall_function(lambda: function(used,as,normal))
```

Comment: Where you wrote "used,as,normal" are these the arguments?

Comment: @Agustin - Yep correct, you're just wrapping the function call inside a lambda function, if your function your passing in doesn't need any arguments, you can just pass in that function name to `overall_function`

Comment: What is the advantage of using this method vs the *args, **kwargs method?

Comment: @Agustin - If `overall_function` needs to take in more than 1 method, then the `args/kwargs` approach won't be able to handle it. Other than that they both have merit depending on use case

Comment: Ah I see, that is good to know.
So if I wanted to pass in more than one method, what would the right way to do so with lambda be?

Comment: `my_func(lambda_1, lambda_2)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Both methods seem useful, have definitely learnt something.